# "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt" blowfish in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, blowfish

I am using the following code

This error occurs :

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupted. Attempted to read or write to protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupted.

```
 Public Function PadBytes(abData() As Byte) As Object

    Dim nLen As Long
    Dim nPad As Integer
    Dim abPadded() As Byte
    Dim i As Long

    'Set up error handler for empty array
    On Error GoTo ArrayIsEmpty

    nLen = UBound(abData) - LBound(abData) + 1
    nPad = ((nLen \ 8) + 1) * 8 - nLen

    ReDim Preserve abPadded(nLen + nPad - 1)  ' Pad with # of pads (1-8)
    If nLen > 0 Then
        CopyMemory(abPadded(0), abData(0), nLen)
    End If

    For i = nLen To nLen + nPad - 1
        abPadded(i) = CByte(nPad)
    Next

 ArrayIsEmpty:
    PadBytes = abPadded

End Function

  Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Byte, Source As Byte, ByVal Length As Long)
```

Please show me the right way.

Comment: Your code looks VB6-ish, especially your CopyMemory declaration.  See [pinvoke: CopyMemory](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/CopyMemory.html)

Comment: yes, it is from VB6, than i tried to use it in vb.net

Comment: You can't.  You have to rewrite it using integers instead of longs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to do the copy like the following

```
CopyMemory(abPadded(0), byval abData(0), nLen)
```

I don't have VB6 any more so you'd need to try it for your self. Fingers crossed it works.